# How can I solve error on then(). in Rest API

Tags: api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

lease review below Code:

```
package API_Testing;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;


public class FirstAPIClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:5100";    
        given().
        header("tenantId","Augusta-PT").
        when().
        get("/WorkExperience");     
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200);


    }

}
```

Error on then statement: The method `then()` is undefined for the type FirstAPIClass

Also, Can i write the code without then, If i dont have to check anything just get response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very small mistake in your code. It is supposed to be `get("/WorkExperience").then()` and not `get("/WorkExperience");then()`

And you can also use it without a then() statement, so your code would be `when().get("/WorkExperience");` and nothing more.

Comment: Thank you so much Wilfred, worked, very much appreciated

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, the tick symbol against my answer to close this question